# How to work with Core Data and iOS 5 storage guidelines?

Tags: iphone, core-data, icloud, file-attributes

I wrote an app that allows users to store text articles in Core Data. I'm using a sqlite backing store.

So what "category of data", as mentioned in [this technical note (login may be required)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html), should my .sqlite data fall into?

I would think "Critical Data" that should not be marked "do not back up". Agreed? However, I also seed the user with about a thousand entries. These entries are technically "regeneratable" and  should be marked "do not back up". The problem is that there is one SQLite file backing my Core Data store, and two kinds of data in it.

Now what? Do I mark the database as "do not back up" and risk losing user data, or do I not mark it as "do not backup" and risk the wrath of the review team, on the grounds that I didn't follow the iOS Data Storeage Guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to consider what would happen if a user, on board an airplane with no network connectivity, started the app after a data purge in a low storage situation?

If the answer is "the app wouldn't work", then that excludes temporary or cached data. Your only decision then is do you want to back up to iCloud or not. This is more about the wrath of  your user for taking up some of their valuable 5GB storage.

Comment: Apple's review team seems to disagree, although I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

Could your case fall under the "CoreData and iCloud" category where your data is synced as diffs as your app modifies them (but this also means really syncing between devices I think):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html